# How can I launch a kernel with "as much dynamic shared mem as is possible"?

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

We know CUDA devices have very limited shared memory capacities, in the tens of Kilobytes only. And we also know kernels won't launch (typically? ever?) If you ask for too much shared memory. And we *also* know that the available shared memory is used both by the static allocations in code that you use and the dynamically-allocated shared memory.

Now, `cudaGetDeviceProperties()` gives us the overall space we have. But, given a function symbol, is it possible to determine how much statically-allocated shared memory it would use, so that I can "fill up" the shared mem to full capacity on launch? If not, is there a possibility of having CUDA take care of this for me somehow?

Comment: I have said this before and I'll say it again, you really would do yourself a huge favour by reading the API documentation through from cover to cover at least once....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime API has a function [cudaFuncGetAttributes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1g19b1696533069c03f646e2ce2beacc00)  which will allow you to retrieve the [attributes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/structcudaFuncAttributes.html#structcudaFuncAttributes_1c3bc6914df6f65ac08b1f53cd7276113) of any kernel in the current context, including the amount of static shared memory per block which the kernel will consume. You can do the math yourself with that information.

Comment: Oh, how very useful!

Answer (score -1):

you also can use nvcc compilation information to get the statically allocation of shared memory

Comment: ... at run time? :-(